# Find the longest String in an array recursively

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static String rMax(String[] s){
    if (s.length == 1){
         return s[0];
    }else {
        String[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1, s.length);
        String maxInNewArray = rMax(newArray);
        String currentString = s[0];
        
        if(currentString.length() > maxInNewArray.length()) {
            return currentString;
        }else 
            return maxInNewArray;
    }
}
```

The above code works but I am looking for an alternative way of coding this one instead of using Arrays.copyOfRange(). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Kerat ! Please be a bit more specific with your question. You said this code does what you require, why do you need an alternative solution?

Comment: If you are willing to convert the array to a list (e.g. `Arrays.asList(s)` ) then you can use `subList(1, s.size())`  instead of `copyOfRange(s, 1, s.length)` as the only significant change to your code and avoid repeated copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a helper adding a start position to consider, avoiding the copy:

```java
public static String rMax(String[] s){
  return rMax(s, 0)
}

public static String rMax(String[] s, int start){
    if (start + 1 == s.length){
         return s[start];
    }else {
        String maxInNewArray = rMax(s, start + 1);
        String currentString = s[start];
        
        if(currentString.length() > maxInNewArray.length()) {
            return currentString;
        }else 
            return maxInNewArray;
    }
}
```